# How can hide and show of direct child list items after nth items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an unordered list, like so:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/63bkkmbf/11/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="nav_accordian">
  <li>One
  <ul>
  <li>on 1.1</li>
  <li>on 1.2</li>
  <li>on 1.3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>One 1</li>
  <li>Two 2</li>
  <li>Three 3</li>
  <li>Four 4</li>
  <li>Five 5</li>
  <li>One 11</li>
  <li>Two 22</li>
  <li>Three 33</li>
  <li>Four 44</li>
  <li>Five 55</li>
</ul>
```

**Script File :**

```
$('.nav_accordian').each(function(){
    var max = 4
    if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><span class="showMore">show More</span></li>');

        $('.sub_accordian').click( function(){
            $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle();

            if ( $('.show_more').length ) {
                $(this).html('<span class="showMore">show More</span>');
            } 
            else {
                $(this).html('<span class="showMore">less More</span>');
            };
        });
    };
});
```

i did for when i click on 'show more' it should be visible all the results of list items . Once every results loaded 'show more' text would be changed on 'less more'.

and when i clicked upon the 'less more' button first five results result items should be visible other items would be hide.

The issue is the script is consider only direct child list of i did for when i click on 'show more' it should be visible next five results of list items . Once every results loaded 'show more' text would be changed on 'less more'.

and when i clicked upon the 'less more' button first results result items should be visible other items would be hide.

but my script is consider li child ul also but i dont want

***i am expected output as:***

**one**

**two**

**three**

**four**

**five**

**Show more**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `>` child selector whenever you want to target the first level children.

```
if ($(this).find('> li').length > max) {
//----------------^
        $(this).find('> li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li ....
//--------------------^
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/63bkkmbf/12/)

Comment: this script when i click on 'show more' it changed 'less more' but 'less more' not changed after

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/63bkkmbf/4/ this script is working fine but when i click on show more i need to show all the results

Comment: @Mgr What is your exact problem? You are showing different codes.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I get confused... but as a contribution, this is the code I did...
HTML:

```
<ul class="nav_accordian">
 <li>One
  <ul>
   <li>on 1.1</li>
   <li>on 1.2</li>
   <li>on 1.3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li>Two
 <ul>
   <li>on 2.1</li>
   <li>on 2.2</li>
   <li>on 2.3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Three
  <ul>
   <li>on 3.1</li>
   <li>on 3.2</li>
   <li>on 3.3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

*Sorry about the indentation.

jQuery:

```
$('.nav_accordian > li').each(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').hide();
  $(this).append('<li class="sub_accordian"><span class="showMore">show More</span></li>');//.children().hide();
}); 

$(document).on('click','.sub_accordian', function(){
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
  if ( $('.show_more').length ) {
    $(this).html('<span class="showMore">show More</span>');
  } 
  else {
    $(this).html('<span class="showMore">less More</span>');
  }
});
```